# Readonly Textbox Highlighted in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface

I have two readonly textboxes that's loaded when the modal is called. The first readonly textbox's text is highlighted in blue.

[image]

This only happens in google chrome. Any idea how to remove the blue highlight? It's the same as clicking on the text and dragging the cursor because when I press ctrl+c, the "Show These Columns" text is copied.

Thank you.

```
<div id="groupvalidator-for-VisibleColumnsList" class="groupvalidator editor-container">
    <input value="Show These Columns" class="editor-group-header " data-val="true" data-val-groupvalidator="You must select at least one column to display." data-val-groupvalidator-pattern="ul.sortable li" data-val-groupvalidator-target="editor-for-VisibleColumnsList" data-val-groupvalidator-title="Column Required" id="VisibleColumnsListValidationHeader" name="VisibleColumnsListValidationHeader" readonly="true" type="text"">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="VisibleColumnsListValidationHeader" data-valmsg-replace="true" style="display: none;">
        <span for="VisibleColumnsListValidationHeader" generated="true">
            <span class="ico-caution"></span>
            <strong></strong>
            <br>
            <br>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".editor-group-header").each(function () {
            $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: A little bit of code?

Comment: Hi, @Samoth. There are a lot of scripts being run in the page but I'm not really sure which one highlights the readonly textbox. Is there some JavaScript code that would do this? jQuery focus?

Comment: I don't know could you provide a link to the page?